# Problem - TCHAR as LPARAM to a window that belongs to another process/thread

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, hook

So i am playing/implementingtomyown with windows via c book examples and there is something about dll injection part that boggles me and i can't solve it.

I created a dialog that belongs to another thread/process and i am trying to send it TCHAR variable so it can then use that var in some function(both the function and tchar are in the same dll file)

So when the dialog is created and sitting well in another thread i send it a message.

First i declare tchar

```
TCHAR finalpath[MAX_PATH];
```

Then later i just fill it with info( i do this in the dll thread, not in the dialog's thread, let me also mention that i must do this in the dll thread because thats only way to fill the required tchar(i am required to get dll working directory and fill it in tchar))

So, when i get this info in my tchar i am trying to send a message to the dialog and use tchar as LPARAM(wparam is hwnd btw)

```
SendMessage(hWndDIPS, WM_APP, (WPARAM) lista, (LPARAM)finalpath);
```

Afterwards i do basic schoolwork in another threads dialog procedure loop...

```
INT_PTR WINAPI Dlg_Proc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

   switch (uMsg) {
      chHANDLE_DLGMSG(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, Dlg_OnClose);

      case WM_APP:


  SaveListViewItemPositions((HWND) wParam, (TCHAR)lParam);
         break;
   }

   return(FALSE);
}
```

Function that is supposed to receive the parameter(this function resides in shared dll and is called by the procedure as you see above is defined as follows..

void SaveListViewItemPositions(HWND hWndLV, TCHAR sejv[]) {
...}

The compiler error i get from this is

```
Error 7 error C2664: 'SaveListViewItemPositions' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'TCHAR' to 'TCHAR []'
```

So i have no idea why is this happening. If tchar is array then i need to use it in parameters with [] added as thats how arrays are used in parameters(not to mention that if i dont do it it gives me more errors and i cant use the parameter in function anyways)

So why is it not converting then?

If there is another solution to make this dialog to receive a tchar var then please explain.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to send data across process boundaries by simply passing a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you're typecasting the LPARAM to a TCHAR instead of an array of TCHARs (TCHAR*).  Try changing that and see if it fixes things.

Comment: That fixes the problem of conversion BUT for some damn reason the tchar variable i pass is empty, i test it by

Comment: _tfreopen(_T("C:/sometext.txt"),_T("w"),stdout);
wprintf(L"%s, ", sejv);
fclose (stdout);
Any idea how i could pass the variable to this dialog that belongs to another thread? I wonder how come i can pass hwnd but not tchar

Comment: Sorry... I'm not that familiar with interprocess communication in Win32. :-(

Answer (score 5):

Even after you'll fix your type declarations and properly cast the `LPARAM` to a `TCHAR*`, your code will be incorrect. The 'parameter' you pass in to that window procedure is a pointer, and as any pointer, is only valid within a process address space. The receiver window will have to use [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and copy the string from your process into its own process. Of course, this implies that the receiver process knows your process id, and has proper privileges to be able to read from your memory. And you also need to pass in the length of the string, since `ReadProcessMemory` cannot guess where the NULL terminator is (although I reckon that with a MAX_PATH max length, this is not a serious issue).

So you are correct, this is a headache, and more so down the road. The privilege issue may be a show stopper.

There are several IPC mechanisms you could use. An easy one is an anonymous named pipe, see [Anonymous Pipe Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Shared memory is another, see [Using Shared Memory in a Dynamic-Link Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). COM would also work (have the process you 'control' create an instance of a class that is hosted in your process server, and let the COM marshaling do the rest, see [Marshaling Details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692621%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). Or you could hand-marshal a COM interface between the process boundary (see [`CoMarshalInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for very precise explanation, what about wm_copydata ? I thought that might be easiest thing to do.

Comment: @Marko29: If you're in control of the code to both processes, and you're using window messages, then WM_COPYDATA is indeed probably the best way to copy a small, simple buffer like a string from one process to another. Just remember that if you're using TCHAR it might mean a different thing in each process unless you're careful to always compile the two as Unicode or ANSI consistent with each other. (You might want to have the sender flag to the receiver whether the buffer is Unicode or ANSI, and have the receiver convert if it needs to. Or always send Unicode no matter what TCHAR is.)

Comment: @Marko29: I didn't even know `WM_COPYDATA` exists actually.

Comment: I solved this with wm_copydata, for some reason strings are the only thing that made me dislike winapi so far. So much converting and compatability issues i had

Comment: But thats what i get when i have no clue about original C and dive into it