# In WinApi How can i send variable to dialog that belongs to another process/thread

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, winapi, mfc

I am in situation where I have tchar variable(with some info in it) and I need to pass it to dialog that belongs to another thread.

I tried by sending a message and `TCHAR` as `LPARAM` but dialog still doesn't see anything when accessing that variable, I guess because the data I send belongs to another process?

What are my options here? Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590497/problem-tchar-as-lparam-to-a-window-that-belongs-to-another-process-thread/4591192#4591192

Comment: Could you clarify - between two threads of the same process or between two processes?

Answer (score 1):

Read via HWND - GetWindowText - SetWindowText.
Your process must have appropriate privileges... ACL
Assume, test-run the code when you are logged in the Windows as Administrators